# Physical Meaning of Minkowski Distance when p > 2

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

Suppose we have two vectors in $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^d$. For $p \geq 1$, the Minkowski distance between these vectors is defined as

$
\lVert u - v \rVert_p = \Bigl( \sum_{i=1}^d \lvert u_i - v_i \rvert^p \Bigr)^{1/p}.
$

This family of distances includes the familiar Euclidean distance ($p = 2$), and the less familiar, but still physically meaningful Manhattan distance ($p = 1$).

When $1 < p < 2$, we can interpret the Minkowski distance as measuring (in a Euclidean sense) a path "between" the paths measured by the Manhattan and Euclidean distance, since

$
\lVert u - v \rVert_2 \leq \lVert u - v \rVert_p \leq \lVert u - v \rVert_1.
$

Is there any physically meaningful or intuitive interpretation when $p > 2$?

Note: I am aware of [this less specific question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/959249/physical-interpretation-or-practical-meaning-of-a-distance).

Comment: As $p$ gets bigger, the contributions of smaller terms get less and less, until only the maximum term is left. For instance, $\lVert(3,4)\rVert_1 = 7$, $\lVert(3,4)\rVert_2 = 5$, $\lVert(3,4)\rVert_3 \sim 4.5$, and $\lvert(3,4)\rVert_\infty = 4$. So raising $p$ "damps out" all the terms but the largest.

Comment: That's true, it becomes a chessboard distance. But it's not obvious to me how (if possible?) to relate a chessboard distance to a Euclidean path in physical space.